# MappingException No usable constructor in interface using Morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

After replacing interface and its implementation I got errors "org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: No usable constructor for ***.Project" where Project is interface and "org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Could not map ... with ID ... in database..." How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If entities are already stored in your database, then such errors will occur. These entities can have "className" field with full class name. If you move a class to another directory, you need to update this field in all entities in the database.